# The ratio of finitely based magmas to all magmas

Tags: combinatorics, universal-algebra, magma

Let $n$ be a positive integer. By $S_n$, I denote the set of positive integers from $1$ to $n$. By $F_n$, I denote the cardinality of the set of magmas on $S_n$ which are finitely based, that is, which have a finite generating set of identities.

I conjecture that the ratio of $F_n$ to the cardinality of the set of all magmas on $S_n$ tends to $0$ as $n$ tends to infinity.

Is this true, and if not, what is the ratio? And has anyone wrote a paper on this topic?

---

*Non-OP edit:*

Here's the precise definition of "finitely based" *(since there's some potential confusion around what "generating set of identities" means - under one interpretation it trivially includes all finite algebras)*:

An algebra $A$ is finitely based iff its equational theory can be axiomatized by finitely many equations (where "equation" is meant in the sense of universal algebra). Equivalently, iff there is a finite set of equations $F$ such that the variety $Mod(F)$ of algebras satisfying each equation in $F$ is exactly the variety generated by $A$. There do indeed exist non-finitely-based finite algebras (including [a three-element magma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4155200/what-is-the-smallest-possible-cardinality-of-a-non-finitely-based-magma)), and in fact the general problem of determining whether a finite algebra is finitely based is extremely complicated - see e.g. [here](https://www2.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/%7Ebarto/student/AUAnotes.pdf).

Comment: How can an algebraic structure with a finite number of elements drawn from some given set **not** be completely described by a finite set of identities?

Comment: @RobArthan Yes, it can. There is a 3-element magma with no finite basis of identities.

Comment: What do you mean by "finite basis of identities"? If a magma is finite, it is completely determined by its operation table, i.e., by a finite set of identities.

Comment: @RobArthan "Finitely based" means that there is a finite set of equations (in the precise sense of universal algebra) which entails every equation (again in that precise sense) true in the structure. A finite structure can have a surprisingly complicated equational theory from this perspective, including - per the above - not being "equationally finitely axiomatizable."

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing the question to say more about the notion of finitely based algebras; feel free to revert or alter as preferred.

Comment: @RobArthan Re: the OP's comment above, see [Eran's answer to their previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4155292/28111).

Comment: @Onir Why is that? Note that the OP is comparing the number of finitely based magmas of size $n$ to the number of magmas of size $n$ in total - I don't think there are enough finite nilpotent groups to answer this question. (Also, the limit can't possibly be $\infty$ - it's $1$ at most.)

Comment: What is the base for your conjecture? For which values of $n$ did you calculate $F_n$?

Comment: @NoahSchweber: thanks for the explanation and clarification.

Comment: I think as n grows, there is a non zero percentage of algebras that are primal (which means their clone has all operations). Primal implies congruence distributive which implies finitely based. I'll check when I get home.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A magma $\mathbf{A}$ is *primal* if for every $n\geq 1$, every operation $A^n\to A$ can arise from a word on $n$ letters. Let $P_n$ be the cardinality of the set of all primal magmas on $S_n$. Let $M_n$ be the cardinality of the set of all magmas on $S_n$.

**Theorem** $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{P_n}{M_n}=1/e\approx 0.368$$

This was supposedly originally proved by R.O. Davies in 1968 and strengthened by V.L. Murskii in the 1970s. I am only familiar with the treatment in Cliff Bergman's "Universal Algebra: Fundamentals and Selected Topics" however.

If every operation can arise as a term operation, then necessarily a primal magma has a sequence of Jonsson operations, ensuring that it generates a congruence distibutive variety (see "Algebras whose congruence lattices are distributive". Bjarni Jonsson. Mathematica Scandinavica, 1968.)

If a finite magma generates a congruence distributive variety, then it must be finitely based (see "Finite equational bases for finite algebras in a congruence-distributive equational class". Kirby Baker. Advances in Mathematics, 1977.)

Hence $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{F_n}{M_n}\geq\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{P_n}{M_n}=1/e>0.$$

**Additional Comment** (Thanks to amsra)

An operation $A^n\to A$ is *idempotent* if $(a,a,\dots,a)\mapsto a$ for all $a\in A$. A magma $\mathbf{A}$ is *idemprimal* if for every $n\geq 1$, every idempotent operation $A^n\to A$ can arise from a word on $n$ letters. Let $I_n$ be the cardinality of the set of all idemprimal magmas on $S_n$. Then Murskii's result was that:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{I_n}{M_n}=1.$$

Since Jonsson operations need to be idempotent, it follows from the above argument that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{F_n}{M_n}=1.$$

Comment: Wow, that's quite surprising to me! +1.

Comment: According to the book [Polynomial Completeness in Algebraic Systems](https://books.google.pt/books?id=YVHDN_EiA0YC&pg=PA341&dq=kaarli+Pixley&hl=pt-PT&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjYjI_IqvbwAhXDy4UKHfzSAQEQ6AEwAHoECAgQAg#v=onepage&q=kaarli%20Pixley&f=false) (p. 119) by Kaarli and Pixley, the strengthening you mention by Murskii was to generalize to quasi primal algebras, proving that $Q_n/M_n\to 1$, where $Q_n$ is the number of quasi primal magmas with $n$ elements. This is the asymptotic limit the OP asks for. However, I only have limited access to the book, so I'm not sure there is no conflicting naming.